# ImportError: No module named core.framework.graph_pb2

Tags: tensorflow

When I follow the Installation for linux from [tensorflow offical site](http://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/os_setup.md), everything is fine until the last step: **Train your first TensorFlow neural net model**.

When I execute the command, `python tensorflow/models/image/mnist/convolutional.py`, An ImportError promps.

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tensorflow/models/image/mnist/convolutional.py", line 13, in <module>
    import tensorflow.python.platform
  File "/home/guo/haplox/Github/tensorflow/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/home/guo/haplox/Github/tensorflow/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework.graph_pb2 import *
ImportError: No module named core.framework.graph_pb2
```

My OS is 14.04.1-Ubuntu.

Comment: Are you installing using `pip`? If so, can you try using `virtualenv`?

Comment: using `virtualenv` solves my problem. Thanks.

Comment: For me, it's because of the tensorflow version. I donwgraded from 1.15 to 1.14 and it worked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have met the exactly same issue.  once your have installed the tensorflow successfully, it's not about the library dependency anymore.

if your executed the convolution.py 100% accurately as manual and get the exception like below

```
ImportError: No module named core.framework.graph_b2
```

this means you are executing the python script exactly under the cloned project root directory,let's say the root named "src".

```
src$python tensorflow/models/image/mnist/convolutional.py
```

please try to execute the script in the parent directory of the cloned root directory. for example, if your just clone the tensorflow under src dir, goto its parent dir like xxx and do it again.

```
xxx$python src/tensorflow/models/image/mnist/convolutional.py
```

bingo, it works like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

Most probably you have either outdated version of:

- [python's six module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/six). Install the newest one (`pip install six`) or upgrade your old one (`pip install --upgrade six`)
- [protobuf](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/protobuf)

Comment: After updating six and rebuilding it from scratch, the  ImportError still happened.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and the solution was to **uninstalled protocol buffer v2.6**.

TensorFlow requires protocol buffer v3.0, which should come with your TensorFlow installation/source. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by using `virtualenv`, but there are many other factors which may cause the same error.

More solutions are at Github issues [#81](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/81), [#61](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/61),
[#51](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/51).

Answer (score 1):

For me, the solution was to run with python3 instead python